# How do I print various phrases depending on the users time?

Tags: javascript

I need to Print "good morning" if the current time is 5am til noon, "good afternoon" if between 12 and 5, "good evening" if between 5 and midnight, and tells someone to go to bed if between midnight and 5am.

The wrong phrase/time keeps printing

Here is my current code:

```js
var today = new Date()
var curHr = today.getHours()

if (curHr < 5) {
  console.log('good morning')
} else if (curHr < 12) {
  console.log('good afternoon')
} else if (curHr < 17) {
  console.log('good evening')
} else {
  console.log('Go to bed')
}
```

Those who said it worked the whole time just happened to live in a timezone where it worked..

Comment: And what is the problem ?

Comment: you should specify what problem you are facing.

Comment: The wrong phrase/time is printing

Comment: No, it works fine. It's 14 here and it prints "good evening", your conditions works fine. You might want to change the phrases or conditions, though.

Comment: it works for me..

Comment: It was printing good afternoon and its 9am where I live...The answer below has seemed to resolve this issue

Comment: The people saying it worked the whole time live in different timezones where it happened to work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to print info based on current time between
Try this

```js
var today = new Date()
var curHr = today.getHours()

if (curHr >= 0 && curHr < 6) {
  console.log('What are you doing that early?');
} else if (curHr >= 6 && curHr < 12) {
  console.log('Good Morning');
} else if (curHr >= 12 && curHr < 17) {
  console.log('Good Afternoon');
} else {
  console.log('Good Evening');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the if conditions. The simplest way is to start with the smallest numbers and therfore in the morning.

If the time is before 5 in the morning you can just start with

`currentHour < 5` and so on...

```js
var today = new Date()
var curHr = today.getHours()

if(curHr < 5) {
  console.log('Go to bed')
} else if (curHr < 12){
  console.log('good morning')
} else if (curHr < 17){
  console.log('good afternoon')
} else if (curHr < 24){
  console.log('good evening')
}
```

Test all times:

```js
var timeArray = [1, 8, 15, 23];

for (var i = 0; i < timeArray.length; i++) {

  var curHr = timeArray[i];
  
  if (curHr < 5) {
    console.log('Current Time (' + curHr + '): Go to bed')
  } else if (curHr < 12) {
    console.log('Current Time (' + curHr + '): good morning')
  } else if (curHr < 17) {
    console.log('Current Time (' + curHr + '): good afternoon')
  } else if (curHr < 24) {
    console.log('Current Time (' + curHr + '): good evening')
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to test from late to early, and keep the conditions to one comparison each

Comment: You've got a mistake in the last `else if` statement.  `curHr` can never be greater than 17 while also being less than 0.

Comment: Thanks @Seblor for the nice hint.

Comment: I also corrected the mistake @MarcusParsons mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can also skip the range check and just check the max hour in descending order.

```js
function greeting() {
  var hour = new Date().getHours();
  if (hour >= 17) return /* 05:00 PM + */ 'Good Evening';
  if (hour >= 12) return /* 12:00 PM + */ 'Good Afternoon';
  if (hour >=  6) return /* 06:00 AM + */ 'Good Morning';
  else            return /* 00:00 AM + */  'What are you doing that early?';
}

console.log(greeting());
```

---

And for some code golf...

```js
var g = {
  17 : 'Good Evening',                  /* 05:00 PM + */
  12 : 'Good Afternoon',                /* 12:00 PM + */
   6 : 'Good Morning',                  /* 06:00 AM + */
   0 : 'What are you doing that early?' /* 00:00 AM + */ 
}
const f=()=>(h=>g[Object.keys(g).map(x=>parseInt(x,10)).sort((a,b)=>b-a).find(k=>h>=k)])(new Date().getHours());

console.log(f());
```